# fixed header working fine for desktop but not for mobile

Tags: html, css

I have used below css for header div of my website

```
.header{
    z-index: 3001;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;left:0px;
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;height:150px;
}
```

This is working fine for desktop. But on mobile, I can only see my 50% of width of the header. On the right side of 50%, nothing is cmg. As in just white background is cmg. On the right side, I have a button which when I click is working.
To say, controls are not visible but they are working if u manage to click at the exact place.
Any fix for this?

I want to add that this problem is coming only in windows phone. So need fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ive always had problems on ios and the width 100% problem. (im assuming this is your problematic mobile).
That said, on your header try somethign like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

See here for a good read. hope this helps.
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/use-iosspecific-meta-tags-in-html5.html

Comment: Made a mistake, sorry